# access parent fragment by child fragment

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

this is my child fragment and how to access my parent fragment from this fragment please help me to fix it

```
public class Profilefragmant extends Fragment {
public Profilefragment(){}
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.profile_layout, container, false);

    TextView VE = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.profile_view_enquiry);
    VE.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        public void onClick (View view){
            Fragment fragment = null;

            fragment = new Enquiryfragment();
            replaceFragment(fragment);
        }
    });



    return rootView;
}
public void replaceFragment(Fragment someFragment) {
    android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    transaction.replace(R.id.containerView, someFragment);
    transaction.addToBackStack(null);
    transaction.commit();
}
}
```

this is my error while run the project

```
 java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No view found for id 0x7f0c0099 (com.knrmarine.knr:id/containerView) for fragment EnquiryActivity{3754711 #2 id=0x7f0c0099}
```

This my `Enquiryfragment` code :

```
public class Enquiryfragmant extends Fragment {
public Enquiryfragment(){}
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.enquiry_layout, container, false);
return rootView;}}
```

Comment: I assume EnquiryActivity is activity so why you use fragment transition with it ? please put the code for EnquiryActivity

Answer (score 90, accepted):

You can get parent `Fragment`'s reference by :

```
ParentFragment parentFrag = ((ParentFragment)ChildFragment.this.getParentFragment());
parentFrag.someMethod();
```

I used this in my ViewPager. If you have other requirement, `Interface` or `EventBus` are two of the general ones.

Comment: Thank you, its working fine and know something new thing.

Comment: Glad it helped you! This question is a year ago, kinda nostalgic that it suddenly appeared on my notifications lol

Comment: Yeah perfect answer, i think this is known as casting, Right ?

Comment: True, @RamkeshYadav. That part `((ParentFragment)ChildFragment.this.getParentFragment())` reads as : I want the parent fragment of the child fragment the code lies in, then cast it into `ParentFragment`. Note that `getParentFragment()` returns `Fragment`.

Comment: Oh and this is the long version of @ArteFact's post. Just to make it clear that this has to be used in the child fragment. If you know what you're doing and want the short version, use theirs instead. Basically cutting `ChildFragment.this` part

Answer (score 27):

Late answer but there is a quite simple way to access a fragment's parent fragment :

**Kotlin**

```
(parentFragment as YourParentFragment).parentFragmentMethod()
```

**Java**

```
((YourParentFragment) getParentFragment()).parentFragmentMethod();
```

Comment: Simplest way. :-)

Comment: get an exception of can't cast NavHostFragment to ParentFragment

Comment: @MoustafaEL-Saghier I think the fragment you're trying to access is just not a subtype of ParentFragment, which is a type of your choosing, ParentFragment is not a real class of the android framework

Comment: @ArteFact i don't get well what you mean but I've two fragments one parent and the other is a child and needs to do an action of changing variable value from child fragment into parent one

Answer (score 6):

**Access Parent Fragment Method from Child Fragment**

```
((YourParentFragmentName) getParentFragment()).yourParentFragmentMethod();
```

**Access Child Fragment Method from Parent Fragment**

```
YourChildFragmentName fragment = (YourChildFragmentName) getChildFragmentManager().getFragments().get(positionOfYourChildFragment);
fragment.yourChildFragmentMethod();
```

Answer (score 3):

Above method did not worked for me (API 26). I found out a new solution here:

```
Fragment fragment = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("MyFragment");

if(fragment != null && fragment instanceof MyFragment)
     ((MyFragment) fragment).someMethod();
else
     Log.e(TAG, "cannot change tab its null...");
```

Answer (score 3):

If you are using kotlin then you can directly use `parentFragment` to access.
Like this

```
parentFragment?.viewPager?.isUserInputEnabled = false
```